# How my asynchronous fs.ReadFile function become synchronus?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, asynchronous

In my node.js express app, I reading a json file's content to my routers with this code:

`lib/functions.js`:

```
'use strict';

const fs = require('fs');

exports.fsAsync = (callback) => {
  fs.readFile(__dirname + '/../database/data.json', 'utf8', (err, data) => {
    if(err) {
      throw callback(err)
    };
    callback(null, JSON.parse(data)); // null means no error, return results in callback
  });
};
```

Which is called in the routers like this:

`routes/contact.js`:

```
'use strict';

const express = require('express'),
      router  = express.Router();

const functions = require('../lib/functions'),
      fsAsync   = functions.fsAsync;

router.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
  fsAsync((err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      return res.render('404', {
        title: 'Error 404'
      });
    }

    const contact = data[2].contact;

    res.render('contact', {
      title: 'Contact',
      data: contact
    });
  });
});

module.exports = router;
```

However I got sync error in the console:

```
(node:12808) WARNING: Detected use of sync API
    at fs.statSync (fs.js:981:18)
    at tryStat (C:\www\node\site\node_modules\express\lib\view.js:169:15)
    at resolve (C:\www\node\site\node_modules\express\lib\view.js:142:14)
    at lookup (C:\www\node\site\node_modules\express\lib\view.js:110:17)
    at View (C:\www\node\site\node_modules\express\lib\view.js:85:20)
    at render (C:\www\node\site\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:569:12)
    at render (C:\www\node\site\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:961:7)
    at fsAsync (C:\www\node\site\routes\contact.js:23:9)
    at fs.readFile (C:\www\node\site\lib\functions.js:18:5)
GET /en/contact 304 154.638 ms - -
```

Someone can help to write this function truly asynchronous?

Comment: It's not your fault, https://github.com/expressjs/express/issues/2960

Comment: Upps, that was also my question a while ago... :) The error presented there without my fsAsync function is showing at `res.render` in the console, which is not async module (right now).

Comment: So probably that's causing this error too, just the "fsAsync" part tricked me.

Comment: Ha ha just seeing the same avatar ))) Anyways, it's the express problem, has nothing to do with your code. Your func is on the stack because you're calling `render` from it.

Answer (score 0):

Why not using directly `fs.readFileSync()`?
For example:

```
var content = fs.readFileSync("file.json", "utf8");
```

Comment: I reading this file in 5-6 routers. I tried to code it once if I make changes to it.

Answer (score 0):

since you are using `.json` file you can use

`require` which also does the job of parsing JSON.

`var myDataObj = require('path_to/data.json');`

Also you can put this require on top of your file and use the `myDataObj`  in your route , so that you will not read `data.json` file on each request and it will act as a cache.